# Codename One - Toast plugin

Tags: codenameone

I am building an app using the GUI builder and wanted to show toast messages. On the plugin description it shows this use:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Hi there", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

"where context is the object passed in the init method of your main class", but when using the GUI builder, there is no *init* method.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is init method in Main class(eg: TestToast.java) and create one public and static variable named context of object type and set its value in init method and whole code is mentioned below.

```
public class TestToast {

private Form current;
   **public static Object context;**
public void init(Object context) {
public class TestToast {

private Form current;
public static Object context;
public void init(Object context) {

    **this.context = context;**
}

public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    new StateMachine("/theme");        
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}
}
```

And you can show toast as below

```
try {
       **Toast.makeText(TestToast.context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**

    } catch (Exception e) {
        showDialog(msg);
    }
```